# Can I insert a block of HTML into an iframe if it has quotation marks?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Essentially, I want to be able to add an accordion to an html document which is displayed in an iframe.  As such, I was trying:

```
function Insert(FRAMENAME, text, replaceContents) {
    document.getElementById('FRAMENAME').focus()
    if(replaceContents==null){replaceContents=false;}
    if(!replaceContents){
        var sel=document.getElementById('FRAMENAME').contentWindow.getSelection()
        sel.collapseToStart()
    }
    HTML = 
        "<div id="accordion">
            <h3>Section 1</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>Text 1</p>
                </div>
            <h3>Section 2</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>Text 2</p>
                </div>
        </div>"
    document.getElementById('FRAMENAME').contentWindow.document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, HTML);
};
```

The problems I'm experiencing at the moment are mainly due to the use of multiple lines (is there a way to leave it formatted in this way but have it all wrapped in the quotation marks?) and with the quotation marks themselves, as there are some IN the HTML, it isn't able to get the full thing (even when the lines are right).

Is there a way around this, like something I should be adding to the end of the line (like ...) to keep it doing, and something to pit instead of or next to the quotation marks to make them appear correctly (in MATLAB you just double up so it's '' instead of ')?

Comment: I am not quite sure you can feed html to an iframe since the iframe is a "window" to another page. That's why it has the src attribute

Comment: Unrelated, but using `FRAMENAME` as a parameter name, then quoting it when you call `getElementById` *may* be what you mean, but I doubt it.

Comment: @Dave Newton I have it slightly differently here to be honest, I may have just put it badly on here.

Comment: @PlaceUserNameHere It seems to be working at the moment, I have contentEditable and designMode on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape your double-quotes with a backslash as well as add a backslash to the end of each line to avoid breaking the string.

```
var HTML = 
"<div id=\"accordion\">\
    <h3>Section 1</h3>\
        <div>\
            <p>Text 1</p>\
        </div>\
    <h3>Section 2</h3>\
        <div>\
            <p>Text 2</p>\
        </div>\
</div>";
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I knew it'd be something simple

Answer (score 1):

Basic Javascript string syntax:

```
var foo = "This string has a double-quote \" in it";
                                          ^--- escape it
```

Comment: I knew it'd be something simple, I just wasn't sure what to google :)